# Basic Authentication on Android

Tags: android, basic-authentication

I found an example

```
try {
        String data = "YOUR REQUEST BODY HERE";
        //
        CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("YOUR USER NAME HERE", "YOUR PASSWORD HERE"));
        //
        DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
        http.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
        //
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut("YOUR HTTPS URL HERE");
        try {
            put.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, "UTF8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncoding: ", e);
        }
        put.addHeader("Content-type","SET CONTENT TYPE HERE IF YOU NEED TO");
        HttpResponse response = http.execute(put);
        Log.d(TAG, "This is what we get back:"+response.getStatusLine().toString()+", "+response.getEntity().toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //
        Log.d(TAG, "Client protocol exception", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException", e);
    }
```

but I have to send a string in the format of the authorization: `<Login>@<ID>:<Passsword>`

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your server is indeed using basic authentication? If it is, you should set the credentials like this:

```
new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Login@ID", "Passsword");
```

Otherwise check what the actual authentication protocol is and implement it (send auth info in header, or as part of URL or as POST parameters, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look first what actually HTTP Basic is: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#section_3

Your question aims not at HTTP Basic and should not be used at all due to being inherently insecure.

I presume what you ask for should be part of the URL. Even with additional measures like SSL I still would not embed credentials in the URL.

HTTP Basic defines how the username and password must be encrypted (actually hashed). No way to have HTTP and the format you asked for.